# Looping through videos in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have this JS code:

```
video_count =1;
videoPlayer = document.getElementById("homevideo");

function run(){
    video_count++;
    if (video_count == 4) video_count = 1;
    var nextVideo = "app/video"+video_count+".mp4";
    videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
    videoPlayer.play();
};
```

and i have two videos i want to play one after another. The videos are playing fine - first one and after ended the second one but this code loop through the second video instead of playing the first video again and after ended the second video etc.

Can you please help?

Thanks in advance,
Yaniv

Comment: Try `video_count++` underneath `.play()`

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ended` event to trigger the `run` function again.

```
video_count =1;
videoPlayer = document.getElementById("homevideo");
function run(){
  if (video_count == 4) video_count = 1;
  var nextVideo = "app/video"+video_count+".mp4";
  videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
  videoPlayer.play();
  video_count++;
};
videoPlayer.addEventListener('ended', run);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
video_count =1;
videoPlayer =     document.getElementById("homevideo");

function run(){
    if (video_count > 2) video_count = 1;
    var nextVideo = "app/video"+video_count+".mp4";
    videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
    videoPlayer.play();
    video_count++;
};
```

will solve the problem
You increase the variable before you define the video's file name, so you begin with two... 
the condition needs to be changed as well, because we wish to set videocount to 1 only after we display the 2nd video

Comment: I am afraid it still doesn't work. Maybe the problem is with var nextVideo? When I declare the path (for example) "http://www.youtube.com/12345" and then +video_count+".mp4"; - the second video isn't playing at all - I have instead black screen. The second video only plays when declaring var nextVideo = "http://www.youtube.com/12345"...

Comment: This is not what the @YanivNoodelman is trying to achieve. He is trying to create a playlist loop where the `n`th video is followed by `n + 1`th. See my answer for a working solution.

Comment: Dear @ Oleander, Can you please advise how to build the JS code to play another type of the same video in case of browser not supporting the type defined as a default? e.g, if not supporting .mp4, play the same vidwo with .webm type.